# Average Mean Sea Level per FIPS Code

Tags: geospatial, county, usgs

I am trying to find the AMSL (average mean sea level) of a bunch of different counties based on their FIPS code. I am hoping there might be a table out there that contains the AMSL that I might be able to join my table to. I have already found the USGS site where I can plug in lat and longs (https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/how-do-i-find-average-elevation-county) but that only gives elevation of that particular spot, I am hoping to find the average value instead of a singular spot.